# Template class C++, trouble writing print and remove for linked list

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I'm doing a project on doubly linked lists that involves the implementation of several member functions. I'm having a little trouble writing a non-class global function and one other function. I'm pretty much done with the project, which involves around 30 member functions, except for these couple things. My header is in a seperate file.

The first one I have trouble with is writing a non-class global print function. Here's the function I need to write. (along with its description)

```
//print out all elements in list l by calling List<T>::print() function.
template <class T>
void operator<<(ostream & os, const List<T> & l){

}
```

here's my List< T >::print() function I wrote, that you're supposed to call in the above function. (along with its description)

```
//print all elements in the list, using character ofc as the deliminator between elements in the list.

template <class T>
void List<T>::print(ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const {
    for (List<T>::const_iterator itr = begin(); itr != end(); ++itr){
        os << *itr << ofc;
    }
}
```

for the second function i need help with, it's "remove(const T & val): delete all nodes with value equal to val from the list". I wrote it, but I just want to know if it works or what you think of it. Because I don't think it will.

```
//delete all nodes with value equal to val from the list.
template<class T>
void List<T>::remove(const T & val){
    for (List<T>::const_iterator itr = begin(); itr != end(); ++itr){
        if (Node *p == itr.val)
        delete p;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm shocked that even *compiles*.:  `if (Node *p == itr.val)`

Comment: I don't think it will lol. My teacher told me to use an iterator so I think the first parts right. I understand the concept but am having trouble with writing it down :P

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is with the `print()` function. Have  you tested it? Does it work?

Comment: Yes I think so. I actually just found the answer to it in another question on this site after doing alot of digging around. I filled it with "l.print(os); return os;". Still don't know howto do the remove function though

Comment: With the remove function, bear in mind that you need to compare each item in the list with the given value; so your comparison will need to use the `val` parameter passed to the function.